# get items from java.util.List within particular ranges of Index

Tags: java, list, sublist

I have an `ArrayList`, lets say: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

How can I want to get elements from the 2nd to 4th index, so the output would be `[3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: `List subArr = mylist.subList(2, 4);`

Comment: @Jhuliano Moreno: thanks to improve my question

Comment: It kind of bothers me how everyone just vomits a function that solves the problem but don't even think that OP have greater problems than solving this issue with a builtin function. If you can't figure out how to do that without using the builtin function you shouldn't be using it and moving on. You should learn how to implement it by yourself.

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno you are right, it is important to know how to do that else he will get stucked when he cannot find any built-in function for a more complicated problem. However the good way of doing it is to use that built-in function. The real problem actually lies in the question itself : it shows that the OP did actually 0 research before asking for help, and maybe the question didn't deserve a proper answer.

Comment: @realUser404 I understand and agree that the best way is using the builtin function. The problem is exactly what you mentioned, encouraging lazyness.

Comment: I am sorry for this !! I am new on StackOverflow. But next time,  I'll do proper research at my end. If not get proper answer, then will post question here. thanks to both

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno That is debatable. I came here looking for something on the List interface that gives me a range. I have no problem writing this function myself, but obviously it would be cleaner to use something that List offers straight out of the box. And to me this question looks like Abi was asking the same question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use List.sublist() as you can find in Oracle documentation :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand the relation to Hibernate. However, you could use [List.subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))

Answer (score 3):

one of the comments is not right.

`List subArr = mylist.subList(2, 4);`

subArr has index between 2,3. not 2,3,4. The upper bound is exclusive